# Insert Multiple value in same time Like Single Variable and Also Array Variable at same time

Tags: php, mysql, database

how to escape and insert in mysql database using php

```
<input type="text" name="job_name">
<input type="text" name="job_code">
<input type="text" name="roles[]">
<input type="text" name="roles[]">
<input type="text" name="roles[]">
<input type="text" name="return[]">
<input type="text" name="return[]">
<input type="text" name="return[]">

$job_name = $_POST['job_name'];
$job_code = $_POST['job_code'];
$rool_weight = $_POST['rools'];
$return_weight = $_POST['return'];
```

how to scape all the value including array and variable. and insert variable repeatly on very row and array..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to insert 3 variables in to $rool_weight, and two into $return_wight?

Comment: i mean they should be one two or many record.. i'm inserting new row using javascript so how many entry have to insert i'll add new row..

Comment: The same way you do it normally, just in a loop...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
// ESCAPE STRING FUNCTION.
function escape_string($string)
{
    global $connection;
    $escape_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
    return $escape_string;
}

// ESCAPE ARRAY FUNCTION.
function escape_array($array)
{
    $arr = is_array($array) ? array_map('escape_string', $array) : $array;
    return $arr;
}

$job_name = escape_string($_POST['job_name']);
$job_code = escape_string($_POST['job_code']);
$rool_weight = escape_array($_POST['rools']);
$return_weight = escape_array($_POST['return']);
```